# jquery UI autocomplete alphabetical ordering

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Please see the following default example

`http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/` (default functionality)

When you type Scala and Schema those results are almost all the way down to the bottom although I would expect them to be first as they both start by S.

I think the reason is that it starts from the top of the list down checking to see if there are any Ss (Actionscript is the first entry in availableTags) and there is no default filtering.

If i was going to use something like cities and I limit the results to 10 and type "S" the first 10 results would not be cities that start by S but whatever contains s and is first in the list.

Is there a way around this ?

[Sample fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/JdQPQ/)

Question2: How can the current entry get highlighted on the displayed results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the jquery plugin selectize.js.
This is how you could do it : http://plnkr.co/edit/1zmretjQGXeVnh74IMRj

As you can see by typing "sc", scala and scheme come first, and are highlighted.